# How can I execute functions in a node.js file hosted by Heroku from a file hosted in a different environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently use host winds to host a html/css/js files. I need to use Node for a new project aspect, and host winds says id have to use a virtual private server. so I figured ill use Heroku, since I have experience deploying to that environment already.

the heroku application has to execute a stripe operation:
(dummy data)

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_NOFBwvYmIyZln2c64bv84A');

stripe.oauth.token({
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: 'ac_123456789',
}).then(function(response) {
  // asynchronously called
  var connected_account_id = response.stripe_user_id;
});
```

followed by a firebase firestore write operation

How can I connect to the heroku environment from a file hosted on Hostwinds? Is it as simple as creating an express server in the node.js heroku deployment, and calling a fetch POST/GET to  an express endpoint from the web page thats hosted by host winds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it as simple as creating an express server in the node.js heroku deployment, and calling a fetch POST/GET to an express endpoint from the web page thats hosted by host winds

Exactly, call one of the routes in your app on heroku servers and then run your function from there.